# Batch: echo to standard out without carriage return line feed

Tags: batch-file, return, line, feed

I thought this would be simple but apparently not.  All the examples I've seen on how to do this are redirecting to a file.  I need to just echo to standard out.

```
    @echo off
    set test = testText
    set test2 = MoreText
    echo %test%%test2%
```

The standard out is then read in via another batch file and it's choking on the CR LF at the end.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite method from the [TSCMD015 FAQ](http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd015.htm) is to use

```
@echo off
set test = testText
set test2 = MoreText
set /p="%test%%test2%"<nul
```